# Allowing parameter name to have "[" in ASP.Net Core WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing

My action method should look like:

```
 public IActionResult GetAll([FromQuery]string page[Number],[FromQuery]string page[Size])
  {
     //code
  }

HTTP Request is like: "GetAll?page%5Bnumber%5D=0&page%5Bsize%5D=100".
```

Problem : the parameter name doesn't allow me to have a square bracket.

Comment: You have to consider that `name[1]` or `name[key]` **is not** a HTML feature. From HTML point of view, they are just names, **not arrays**. It's only that some server-sided applications/languages (such as PHP) interpret that as arrays. But again, it's not a standard and you should **not depend** on the fact that `name[key]` represents a kind of dictionary / list

Comment: Same applies for Get parameters: `index?a=1&a=2` is just tat: 2 values for a; once with 1 and once with two. It's not an array and not defined in HTML/Http Standard. Every language decide what tzo do, i.e. only count the first, or last. Some may make an array of it others only if it's `a[]=1&a[]=2`, but it wholly depends on implementation. That's why you should avoid using such terminologies/patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides, that I'd go for simpler names of the parameters, you can solve this by using a dictionary:

```
public IActionResult GetAll(Dictionary<string, string> page) {
  var x = page["Number"];
  var y = page["Size"];
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over endpoints :) I would have made it simpler too! Thanks!